# bind method not work

Tags: javascript, bind

```
         var tap = {tap:"tap tap tap",

                  trrap : function (){
                  alert(this.tap);
                  }
};
          var tab = {tap:"tab tab tab",

                      trrab: function (){tap.trrap.bind(this);};
};
tab.trrab();
```

I want to pass tab object to a function in tap object,it would be like `alert(tab.tap);` . Both of it have tap property.

Comment: Where do call bind() in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called the bound function. `bind` returns a function it does not call it.

```
var tap = {
    tap:"tap tap tap",
    trrap : function (){
        alert(this.tap);
    }
};
var tab = {
    tap:"tab tab tab",
    trrab: function (){
        tap.trrap.bind(this)();
    }
};
tab.trrab();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqEXs/

Also you could use `call` to set the context and call it immediately.

```
tap.trrap.call(this);
```

or `apply`

```
tap.trrap.apply(this);
```

Comment: If it return the actual function, so this is like immediately invoke after the function has return?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but `bind` returns a function with the set context. The function is not called you'll have to call it in your code.